# .net web service inquiry

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, iis-7

I have a sample web service deployed on my IIS but can only be accessed using a secured connection (https) --port 443 by default.  Does it also mean that my web service is secured already?

Considering that I only use a self-signed certificate for testing purposes and will use a signed certificate in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by secured? It is secure in the sense that the data communicated between the consumer and server is safe from interception , but it does not mean that the inputs the to service are safe, if that makes sense

Comment: Secured by means of "safe from middle man attacks".  I think to elaborate this more precisely, once my .net web service is deployed under https protocol, it's already safe and secured?  Or there are other points of exploit that I needed to reconsider?

Comment: Yes, for the most part. There's still the capability of interception via a rogue certificate, but that's quite unlikely, and usually only at "government" scale. Basically SSL will keep you protected from people intercepting the network traffic and being able to look at the contents.